# Nesting multiple dictionaries made from user input

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
def individualstudent():
  count=1
  for i in range (1,3):
      sname=input('Enter name for student '+str(count) +' : ')
      sID=int(input('Enter ID for student '+str(count)+' : '))
      smark=int(input('Enter mark for student '+str(count)+' : '))
      studno=('student'+str(count))
      studno={'name':sname,'ID':sID,'mark':smark}
      totaldict[count]=studno
      count+=1

  print(totaldict)
individualstudent()
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary containing 200 dictionaries.
However, when I try to print the momma dictionary only the most recent one will print.

Comment: What should the final dict look like? I'm guessing it would contain 200 smaller dicts as its values, but what are the keys?

Comment: 'name 'ID' and 'mark' are the keys, in the third last line

Comment: But what are the keys of the parent dict? You can't store _just_ dicts in the parent dict; every dict has to be associated with a key. Please [edit] the output you want to get into the question (but not with all 200 sub-dicts; a small representation will do).

Comment: Thanks, that;s what I didn't realise I'll store them some other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `bracket` notation in order to add elements to dictionary.

```
totaldict = {}
for i in range (1,201):
   ........................ 
   totaldict[count] = studno
```

Comment: I'm trying to add 201 dictionaries to a dictionary, I only want one totaldict not 201

Comment: @Laura_, don't forget to define the dictionary before the for loop. Have a look to updated answer.